# JavaScript array expressions return object literal in one line

Tags: javascript, arrays

Its known that someone can make a one-line array function like this to return the single value:

```
var func = (x) => x + 1 //func(2) == 3
```

and you can also make multi-line array-functions, whose values need to be manually returned:

```
var funcMultiline = (x) => {
   var result = 1;
   result += x;
   return result;
}

funcMultiline(4) == 5; //true
```

So the question: 
let's say I want to return a new object in one line, if I use the brackets, then the array-function is treated like a multi-line function, and doesn't actually return the object-literal. Is there any direct way to create an object literal in, lets say, a map function? Like:

```
[...Array(25)].map(e => {x: 5, y:10}) //this is a syntax error, but how can I make this work
```

Comment: You need to add brackets: `[...Array(25)].map(e => ({x: 5, y:10}))`

Comment: For the record, these are not "array functions". They are called "arrow functions" in JS and sometimes "lambda functions" (usually by people coming outside JS).

Answer (score 4):

[Returning object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals) using the concise body syntax `params => {object:literal}` will not work as expected.

You have to wrap the object literal with parenthesis:

```js
var res = [...Array(25)].map(e => ({x: 5, y:10}))

console.log(res);
```